# Extending Prism IContainerRegistry to register by name specifying constructor

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism, unity-container, dryioc

I'm trying to migrate a Prism WPF application whitch is using Unity IoC container to use DryIoC container.

In a module I have the Unity container injected to register a class specifying the constructor.

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IService, Service>(
    typeof(Service).FullName,
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    Invoke.Constructor(
        Resolve.Parameter<IDependency1>(), 
        Resolve.Parameter<IDependency2>()...
    ));
```

I wanted to migrate this type of registers to use `IContainerRegistry` methods to register. I've seen that `IContainerRegistry` interface provides methods to regiser using Factory method whitch I can use to specify constructor, but there is no method with factory method as parameter and named register also.

Does anybody have the same problem? Maybe extending the IContainerRegistry implementation?

Comment: Could you register directy to DryIoc IRegistrator? If it exposed somewhere you may use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just skip `IContainerRegistry` and call the `GetContainer` extension method and use the actual container.

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterDelegate<IDependency1, IDependency2, IService>( (a, b) => new Service(a,b), serviceKey: typeof(Service).FullName, reuse: Reuse.Singleton );
```

`IContainerRegistry` is just a thin wrapper around the container without any defined behavior of its own. For anything but the most trivial registrations, you have to go to the container anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know that it's a wrapper, but in modules if you don't want to have the concrete IoC dependency you cannnot access the extension. I didn't want to include dependency to avoid as much as possible couple my code to IoC container. But it seems it's the only way or adapt my constructors

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether your code depends on `IContainerRegistry` or `IUnityContainer` or `IContainer`, as long as no code outside of the resolution root uses any of these, does it?

Comment: In this case not. I'm talking about a Prism Module but I wanted to decouple modules from the IoC container dependency and have the IoC container dependency only in the Prism application. I wanted in this way to avoid problems if I have to change the IoC container in the future like I'm doing now because of Unity deprecation.

Comment: `IContainerRegistry` is a ioc container dependency, too. You could split the module into two assemblies (one with the modularization and ioc dependencies, one without), but the module definition, as part of the resolution root, always will have a dependency on the ioc container in one way or another.

Comment: I understand, the difference is that if you change from Unity to DryIoc you have to change Prism.Unity to Prism.DryIoc only on app package or also in Modules. That's the reason of my question.